# When I type 'npm run dev', server is running but not bring up a webpage

Tags: web, npm, server

I'm making chatbot webapp with dialogflow by cloning.
When you type 'npm run dev', it is supposed to bring up a webpage but there's nothing happen even though the server is clearly running as the image below.

[refer this image plz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da80m.png)

Appreciate you all! :)

Comment: why do you think starting your server should automatically "bring up a webpage" (I suppose you mean starting the browser and opening that page)?

Comment: @derpirscher Ah yes your words are exactly right. but when I clone by Youtube video tutorial, it seems like it starts the browser.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG5x48D6QE0